# Element Declaration Consistency

Tags: xml, xsd

The Element Declaration Consistency specifies that in a particular content model, two elements of the same name must have the same type. But, what is the use of such a constraints and what implication can it have if it is not respected

Answer (score 0):

The constraint you mention ensures that if we know the path from the validation root to a node, and the element declaration, attribute declaration, or type definition with which validation started, then we know what type the node should have.  We do not need to check where it is among its siblings; the first `foo` child of any element and the fifth `foo` child of that element will have the same declared type.

Some type systems (such as that used in XQuery and XSLT) exploit that fact.

If the constraint is not followed, the implication is just that the schema in question is not a conforming schema, so schema validation as defined by the XSD spec is not possible.